# Why is year 1900 not returning False?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    if (year%4==0 & (year%100!=0)) | (year%4==0 & year%100==0 & year%400==0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(is_leap_year(1900))
```

I would like for the argument (1900) to yield a False, since both sides of the or ( | ) statement fails to be true. What am I missing? This is written in Python.

Comment: The boolean and/or operator in Python are the words `and` and  `or`, not the ampersand and vertical bar.  Those are bitwise operators.

Comment: Don't use `&` and `|` when you mean `and` and `or`; they don't short-circuit. and their precedence is higher than the comparison operators.

Comment: `a == b & c == d` is the same as `a == (b & c) == d`, not `(a == b) & (c == d)`.

Comment: You also don't need an `if` statement; the Boolean you use in the condition is the value you want to return, so just return it directly.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your input. @chepner yes, I can see that now, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
def is_leap_year(year):
    if (year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or (year%4==0 and year%100==0 and year%400==0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(is_leap_year(1900))
```

& and | are bitwise AND and OR respectively, not logical operators.